# Morse code representation not working in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, sound

The example source code for reproducing Morse code as sound does not work in Ubuntu:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <ctime> 

using namespace std;

const string S_DOT = "\a";
const string S_BAR = "\a\a\a";

inline void timeSleep(clock_t sec)
{
    clock_t start_time = clock();
    clock_t end_time = sec * 1000 + start_time;
    while(clock() != end_time);
}//timeSleep

inline void shortPause()
{
    timeSleep(1);
}//shordPause

inline void longPause()
{
    timeSleep(2);
}//longPause


int main()
{
    // SOS in Morse code
    cout << S_DOT;
    shortPause();
    cout << S_DOT;
    shortPause();
    cout << S_DOT;
    shortPause();
    cout << S_BAR;
    shortPause();
    cout << S_DOT;
    shortPause();
    cout << S_DOT;
    shortPause();
    cout << S_DOT;
    shortPause();

    return 0;
}
```

My sound settings should be OK as I am able to open and listen to music (i.e. from YouTube). Could you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

For a `tty`:

1. Load the driver for the pc speaker:

   ```
   sudo modprobe pcspkr
   ```
2. Check in `alsamixer` that the Pc speaker/beep is not muted and the volume is turned up.
3. Switch to `tty1`: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and test the beep:

   ```
   echo -e '\a'
   ```

If it works, you can run your program from the tty.

For `X`:

In `X` the beep is handled by X and pulseaudio should produce a sound for it, but some terminals doesn't produce the sound, so try it in `xterm` to make sure if it is not working.